# apt-mirror vs debmirror and mirror size

Tags: repository, apt-mirror

I've recently inherited the admin of a group of Ubuntu servers (12.04 LTS), including a local mirror server. This is using a script to update itself with debmirror. What are the relative pros and cons of debmirror over apt-mirror? My previous Linux experience is limited: we are a mainly Windows site and I got assigned this because I've looked after one or two Solaris boxes in the past!

Also, I'm wanting to add 14.04 LTS to the mirror. Is there any way to work out what volume of storage I'll need for the two releases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is much difference. But instead take a look at [apt-cacher-ng](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) for an alternative way of doing mostly the same thing, with less work for you and less bandwidth waste.

deb/apt-mirror blindly copies all files (even if some are never used) from the distro/architecture/version you specify, periodically according to cron, etc.

But apt-cacher-ng is passive. When some user pulls a package, that package remains in your server for the next person. Similar to [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), unless there is a newer version online which then gets pulled and also kept.

And it happens to work with all apt distros just fine without you doing any extra work or adding anything else, third party repositories and ppas they all get stored (cached) in your server.

For your users to use apt-cacher-ng they only need to add a proxy to their apt configuration, instead of using a local mirror.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. One of the reasons we use a local mirror is that it is the only machine that has access through the firewall to download packages from public sources. Would this preclude the use of apt-cacher-ng or do the downloads still come via the local mirror?

Comment: @Firstbass Late comment, but it's no problem to keep that setting with apt-cacher-ng.

Comment: A mirror is not a cache and a cache is not a mirror :-)